# Render Partial View to HTML string in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use AJAX to call my Controller and return a Partial View with a model as a string so that I can inject it into my HTML. I have done this before in MVC5 using a controller interface, but I can't seem to find anything on how to do this for a Partial View in Asp.Net Core 2.2. I have found examples of how to render a View to a string, but I could not modify them to work for a partial view.

Controller Action:

```
    public JsonResult GetUpsertPartialView(MessageBoard messageBoard)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string errorState = "0";
        string errorMessage = "";

        try
        {
            result["view"] = ""; // My call to render the Partial View would go here.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errorState = "1";
            errorMessage = "An error was encountered while constructing the View.";
        }
        result["errorState"] = errorState;
        result["errorMessage"] = errorMessage;
        return Json(result);
    }
```

AJAX Call:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "../Home/GetUpsertPartialView/",
      data: messageBoardData,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
         $("#messageBoardModalBody").val(data.view);
         $("#messageBoardModal").modal("show");
      }
   });
```

I've confirmed that my Controller is being hit, the parameters are being passed correctly, and I'm receiving the correct data back from the Action to my AJAX call. The only thing I'm missing is the ability to render a Partial View directly to a string.

If there is another way to do this in Asp.net Core, I'm open to other options.

Note: I'm just doing this to learn Asp.Net Core. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why Json result with html string? You can return a partial view directly to return html.

```
public IActionResult GetUpsertPartialView(MessageBoard messageBoard)
{

    return PartialView("someviewname", messageBoard);
}
```

Comment: Most times I need to return additional data aside from the   Partial View. Specifically, I need to be able to return error data in most cases. That is why I want to return it as part of a Json result.

Comment: I would either return json and use the json to build the html, or I would just return the partial view, if some error happens I would just return NotFound() instead of the partial view and the ajax can know that was an error by the status code.

Comment: That is a good idea. I suppose I don't really need to return a specific error message since it is logged in my application. I can return different status codes as needed instead. That meets all my requirements, so I'll mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeAudette I really _am_ returning additional data. I certainly could build the HTML in javascript, but why would I want to take an HTML partial, convert it to JSON, and then build HTML from the JSON?

Answer (score 7):

**The ControllerExtensions implementation**

```
    public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Render a partial view to string.
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync(this Controller controller, string viewNamePath, object model = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewNamePath))
            viewNamePath = controller.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            try
            {
                var view = FindView(controller, viewNamePath);

                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    controller.ControllerContext,
                    view,
                    controller.ViewData,
                    controller.TempData,
                    writer,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return $"Failed - {exc.Message}";
            }
        }
    }

    private static IView FindView(Controller controller, string viewNamePath)
    {
        IViewEngine viewEngine = controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;

        ViewEngineResult viewResult = null;

        if (viewNamePath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
            viewResult = viewEngine.GetView(viewNamePath, viewNamePath, false);
        else
            viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewNamePath, false);

        if (!viewResult.Success)
        {
            var endPointDisplay = controller.HttpContext.GetEndpoint().DisplayName;

            if (endPointDisplay.Contains(".Areas."))
            {
                //search in Areas
                var areaName = endPointDisplay.Substring(endPointDisplay.IndexOf(".Areas.") + ".Areas.".Length);
                areaName = areaName.Substring(0, areaName.IndexOf(".Controllers."));

                viewNamePath = $"~/Areas/{areaName}/views/{controller.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"]}/{controller.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"]}.cshtml";

                viewResult = viewEngine.GetView(viewNamePath, viewNamePath, false);
            }

            if (!viewResult.Success)
                throw new Exception($"A view with the name '{viewNamePath}' could not be found");

        }

        return viewResult.View;
    }

}
```

**Usage in your controller actions:**

```
var html = await this.RenderViewToStringAsync("actionName" , model);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get a partial view's (or several) from any where (a controller, page model etc) using a service:

[The Origin of this answer](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/), he deserves the credit (I'm adding it here because I needed something like that and it took me quite a while to find it)

### Defining the interface for the Dependency Inejection

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
}
```

### The service's implementation

```
public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

### Adding the class in the `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
```

### Finally, Using the service

```
string html = await m_RenderService.RenderToStringAsync("<NameOfPartial>", new Model());
```

Comment: I'm terribly afraid this (or variants) really is the only solution. It's horribly cumbersome to get a string representation of a single Partial.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Aharon's answer, which addresses the OP's "pure" title question of how to render a partial as a string, I'm adding my own solution below. Mine is to do this straight from with a controller action.

Of course, the OP shouldn't use this in their use-case as the excepted answer is correct.

The `CreateViewModelAsync` method is your own.

```
// SomeController.cs

public SomeController(
    IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator, ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine,
    IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IViewBufferScope bufferScope,
    HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, UrlEncoder urlEncoder,
    ModelExpressionProvider modelExpressionProvider)            
{
    this.viewEngine = viewEngine;
    this.cardHtmlHelper = new HtmlHelper<TimesheetCardModel>(
        htmlGenerator, viewEngine, metadataProvider, bufferScope,
        htmlEncoder, urlEncoder, modelExpressionProvider);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("test", Name = "TestRoute")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
{
    // Example renders a partial view as HTML using MotherModel.Children.First() as
    // the model for the partial.

    MotherModel viewModel = await this.CreateViewModelAsync();

    const string viewName = "_MyPartial";

    var foundView = this.viewEngine.FindView(this.ControllerContext, viewName, false);
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<FirstChildModel>(this.ViewData);
    
    var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, foundView.View, viewData, this.TempData, textWriter, new HtmlHelperOptions());
    
    this.cardHtmlHelper.Contextualize(viewContext);

    var htmlContent = await this.cardHtmlHelper.PartialAsync(viewName, pageModel.Children.First(), viewData);

    htmlContent.WriteTo(textWriter, HtmlEncoder.Default);

    var html = textWriter.ToString();

    ...
}
```